# Como denegar accesos de url si no se ha logueado

Tags: php

Tengo este código el cual es un administrador, la función es que al loguearse no redirija sino que solo incluya el documento .php y todo funciona rebien el problema es que cuando no me he logueado y pongo en la url admin.php por ejemplo ingresa al archivo admin.php obviamente sin estilos ni nada pero ingresa entonces quiero saber que fragmento de código poner en el mio y en que parte.

Les dejo mi código

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once("header.php");
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {

  if (isset($_GET['close'])) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    include_once("login.php");
  } else {
    include_once("admin.php");
  }
} elseif ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

  require_once 'include/conexion.php';

  $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass' LIMIT 1");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) === 1) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
      include_once("admin.php");
  } else {
      include_once("login.php");
   }
} else {
   include_once("login.php");
}
include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Lo ideal sería que utilices un middleware (https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2016/05/31/why-care-about-php-middleware/) es posible que lo hagas mediante las variables de sesión, supongo que en tu login cuando el usuario se logea puedes retornar una variable global.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas común en estos casos es usar htaccess. Crear un archivo .htaccess dentro de la carpeta con la regla

```
Deny from all
```

La otra opción es mover los archivos si es posible, a una carpeta fuera del directorio principal que comúnmente es llamado public_html

Comment: el problema esta en que si le pongo eso a mi .htaccess no me carga mi documento pues por permisos me sale